# Textures in Unity Messed Up

Tags: texturing, uv

I've been trying to make a textured model of a Gewehr 34 for my game. I imported a texture onto a certain part of the gun in Unity and the textures are messed up and different angles/sizes. Anyone have any idea why this is?

[image: In unity]

Comment: looks like you didn't do the UV map in blender properly? can you share your source blend file on https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.